# what does '../..'mean in node,js

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I am newbie to nodejs and expressjs and recently i look up some experimental projects for express official github site and found `../..` as the link:https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/static-files/index.js
Code snippet downside:

```
var express = require('../..');
var logger = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
```

I guess express is required from somelocation through'../..'.And this snippet is not the main part of project,but curiosity can not make me hand down.Thanks,I wanna truth.

Comment: If you are searching for the truth then always go to the source: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html

Comment: I found the prescription before but I did not found detail about this issue.

Comment: It's a standard way in the nowadays operating systems to denote a path that is two levels up of the current directory. The parent directory of the parent directory of the current directory. Not a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means to go back 2 folder levels and load the `index.js` file.

Comment: why not use `../../`?